# How do I bind an html inline onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use an inline onclick handler, but I need to bind to the this context that it is created in, not the this of the dom element itself, but for the life of me I can't get this to work:

```
onclick="${this._sortTable.bind(this, i)};"
```

Please put me on the right track.

I'm using es6 with template literals:

```
var container = `<div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 ${WIDTH} !important" data-index="${columnObject.index}" onclick="${this._sortTable.bind(this, i)};">${columnObject.title}</div>`;
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

The dom element definitely looks strange:

```
<div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 5.555555555555555% !important" data-index="column7" onclick="function () { [native code] };">COLUMN7</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some libraries beyond just javascript ... can you tell us what they are?

Comment: @theGleep The code at OP does not necessarily need to have a library included

Comment: It could have a big impact on how the onclick handler is interpreted.

Comment: I have jquery, kendo, react, the list goes on and on. Unfortunately, what I'm doing is working with leaflet, but at the end of the day, this is a simple inline onclick that I'm trying to .bind, but turns out to not be so simple.

I'm using ES6 template literals:

var container = `<div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 ${WIDTH} !important" data-index="${columnObject.index}" onclick="${alert.bind(this, this.options.id)};">${columnObject.title}</div>`;

Comment: Thanks for the reformat - it makes the question more clear.

Comment: With that code, you're trying to treat the output of "bind" as a string when it gets inserted into the DOM.  Do you have the option of creating the object, attaching the handler, then adding it to the DOM?

Comment: Yeah, just was hoping not to have too :) What we do is a bit different than your general environment, so some simple tasks become very tedious. Besides, I was curious as to why I simply cannot just .bind the this context.

Comment: Try printing/inspecting container, I think you'll see what's really going wrong.

Comment: added edit to initial question. dom element definitely looks strange, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I'm going to do what you recommended earlier, create the element and attach the data attributes and onclick handler. Let's see if that works. If you add that as an answer, I'll give you a thumbs up if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `_sortable` as a `static` function of the `class`

```js
class FN {
  constructor(prop) {
    const div = `<div onclick="FN._sortable(${prop})">click</div>`;
    console.log(div);
    document.body.innerHTML += div;
  }
  static _sortable(n) {
    console.log(n)
  }
}

let c = new FN(123);
```

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't work in our environment. FN comes back as undefined. Getting things into the global context requires too many bureaucratic decisions and too much effort. I'll figure another way around this. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

With that code, you're trying to treat the output of "bind" as a string when it gets inserted into the DOM.

The most obvious solution is to create the DOM object first, then attach your handler to the object, then insert your object into the DOM.

You might not even need to use bind to get access to the "this" object - especially if you created a "me" alias.

Comment: Tried that and couldn't get it to work. Ultimately, I had to add an external event handler, which I'm having a problem with. I'm using leaflet, so I'm having problems attaching the event handler on top of the leaflet map layer. Anyhow, that's an entirely different issue. I was just hoping for an easy workaround, but so far, no go. Thanks for the idea though.